# MySQL a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have child table my_contacts and parent table profession.
profession table is created with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE profession(
    prof_id INT NOT NULL,
    profession VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

now I am trying to add a foreign key in my_contacts table by this command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
ADD COLUMN prof_id INT NOT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT profession_prof_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (prof_id)
REFERENCES profession (prof_id);
```

I get this error:
Error 1052 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the prof_id column which was foreign key in my_contacts table and added it as a column which can accept null values and I could make it a foreign key.